# Installing celery for django

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am a little confused on what i should install for celery to work with my django installation.I have celery and django installed.I want my service broker to be redis and this package is given

> django-celery-with-redis 3.0
>
> at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-with-redis/

There is this other package

> django-celery
>
> at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

When i install *django-celery-with-redis 3.0*  package,does it include *django-celery* package?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i install django-celery-with-redis 3.0 package,does it include django-celery package?

Yes. As noted on the [homepage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-with-redis/),

> This bundle installs the following packages:
>
> ```
> ['django-celery>=3.0,<4.0', 'redis>=2.4.4']
> ```

You will, of course, have to install Redis itself separately.